# How to push notification when your app is turn off, and without firebase?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am working on weather app project, I am using android-studio, and I would like to get a notification of the weather, even if, and especially when my application is turn off (1 notification per day, or 1 notification when you turn on your device).
However, I don't use Firebase or any cloud, and I don't want.

How can I do that with flutter ?

I know about android_alarm_manager, but I don't know if it's the best way to do it. Or maybe, I should learn native iOS and android before to learn Futter ?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you actually want to do is to schedule a background task periodically. In the background task, perform a HTTP request to download the latest weather data. That will be dramatically easier than a home-made push notification service.

Flutter does not provide an API for background tasks (July 2018). I would recommend you to take a look at native development. You can still use Flutter for UI development, and add the native code in the `android`/`ios` folders in your Flutter project.

Google recently released [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) for background tasks on Android, which replaces previous third-party libraries.

I'm not sure about iOS.

Comment: I used the package : flutter_local_notifications 0.3.6 (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_local_notifications), and it's working on flutter. **Even if my app is off, on android AND iOS**, I can receive notification. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: i have the same problem ...can you help me ?. @Fabien